# Is it possible to create integration flow beans from different property values by using BeanFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

My intention is to create IntegrationFlow bean instances from various sources/directories(for the first place, later maybe from ftp). Therefore in the `application.properties` I'd like to define something like this, the number of inbound directories may vary:

```
inbound.file.readPath[0]=source1
inbound.file.processedPath[0]=processed1
inbound.file.failedPath[0]=failed1

inbound.file.readPath[1]=source2
inbound.file.processedPath[1]=processed2
inbound.file.failedPath[1]=failed2
```

I'd also like to maintain the origin of the sources (via header enrichment) so it is not an option to put all files into one directory outside from spring.

**So having a FilePollingFlow is it possible to create these bean instances from the above mentioned properties?** I could imagine something like this, but I am not sure how to pass the properties to the bean instances and how to reference the indices:

```
@Configuration
public class FilePollingIntegrationFlow extends AbstractFactoryBean<IntegrationFlow> {

    @Autowired
    private FilePollingConfiguration config;

    @Override
    public Class<IntegrationFlow> getObjectType() {
        return IntegrationFlow.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected IntegrationFlow createInstance() throws Exception {
      return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s -> /* FIXME config.getReadPath()? instead of inboundReadDirectory, but how to handle indices? */s.file(inboundReadDirectory).preventDuplicates(true).scanEachPoll(true).patternFilter("*.txt"),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(inboundPollingPeriod)
                                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
                                .transactional(transactionManager())))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, getClass().getName(), "'Read inbound file: ' .concat(payload)")
                .enrichHeaders(m -> m.headerExpression(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, "payload"))
                .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                .channel(ApplicationConfiguration.FILE_INBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .get();
   }
}
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("inbound")
public class FilePollingConfiguration {

private List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

public static class File {
    private String readPath;
    private String processedPath;
    private String failedPath;

    public String getReadPath() {
        return readPath;
    }

    public void setReadPath(String readPath) {
        this.readPath = readPath;
    }

    public String getProcessedPath() {
        return processedPath;
    }

    public void setProcessedPath(String processedPath) {
        this.processedPath = processedPath;
    }

    public String getFailedPath() {
        return failedPath;
    }

    public void setFailedPath(String failedPath) {
        this.failedPath = failedPath;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                .append("readPath", readPath)
                .append("processedPath", processedPath)
                .append("failedPath", failedPath)
                .toString();
    }


    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the several similar flows the Framework provides for you a solution like `IntegrationFlowContext`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows. So, what you need is just an iteration over those files and creation flows on the fly and their registration.

Regarding list of similar properties like you inner `File` you should revise the recommendations from Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml.

Pay attention to the `servers` property there. I mean if you call it `files` in the Java class, that has to be `files` in the properties file.

**UPDATE**

This is how it works for me:

my `application.properties`

```
my.source.dirs=/tmp/in1,/tmp/in2
```

The app is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49168720Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(So49168720Application.class, args);

        File file1 = new File("/tmp/in1", "foo.txt");
        file1.createNewFile();
        FileCopyUtils.copy("FOO".getBytes(), file1);

        File file2 = new File("/tmp/in2", "bar.txt");
        file2.createNewFile();
        FileCopyUtils.copy("BAR".getBytes(), file2);


        PollableChannel resultChannel = applicationContext.getBean("resultChannel", PollableChannel.class);

        System.out.println(resultChannel.receive(10000));
        System.out.println(resultChannel.receive(10000));

        file1.delete();
        file2.delete();
    }

    @Value("${my.source.dirs}")
    private String[] sourceDirs;

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;


    @PostConstruct
    private void registerFilePollingFlows() {
        Arrays.asList(this.sourceDirs).forEach(inboundSource -> {
            IntegrationFlow flow =
                    IntegrationFlows
                            .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(inboundSource))
                                    .patternFilter("*.txt"))
                            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, getClass().getName(),
                                    "'Read inbound file: ' .concat(payload)")
                            .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                            .channel(resultChannel())
                            .get();

            this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
        });
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerSpec defaultPoller() {
        return Pollers.fixedDelay(1000);
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel resultChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

}
```

And I have in the logs these messages:

```
2018-03-13 17:43:05.148  INFO 19676 --- [ask-scheduler-3] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fda2b12 : Read inbound file: \tmp\in2\bar.txt
2018-03-13 17:43:05.148  INFO 19676 --- [ask-scheduler-2] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4fda2b12 : Read inbound file: \tmp\in1\foo.txt
GenericMessage [payload=BAR, headers={file_originalFile=\tmp\in2\bar.txt, id=4a692a68-3871-b708-a28e-c4dc378de7e5, file_name=bar.txt, file_relativePath=bar.txt, timestamp=1520977385150}]
GenericMessage [payload=FOO, headers={file_originalFile=\tmp\in1\foo.txt, id=32597359-6602-3df6-5f6f-dac2f4ad788f, file_name=foo.txt, file_relativePath=foo.txt, timestamp=1520977385150}]
```

However this is already based on the Spring Integration `5.0` and Spring Boot `2.0`. Any reason do not upgrade your project ?

Comment: Thank you also for the property recommendations! One more thing, shall I put this iteration into a `@PostConstruct` annotated method?

Comment: I think so. Did you try and it doesn’t work somehow?

Comment: Now I have something like this:
[link](https://pastebin.com/EamgE71u)
But the files did not picked up from the inbound read folders

Comment: Looks good. Would you mind to turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` and take a look what's going on with those `FileReadingMessageSource`s and what make you think they don't read files? Some simple Spring Boot app to play with would be great too.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a sample project on github and share the link here. 
There is a `.log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, getClass().getName(), "'Read inbound file: ' .concat(payload)")` which not logs anything.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.